# Computing an infinite sum of time-shifted sequence

Tags: dft, dtft

Given a discrete-time domain signal $x[n]$ defined as

$$x[n] = \begin{cases}1 & 0 \leq n \leq L-1 \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

we are tasked with computing $$\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}x[n-kR]$$ where $R = \frac{L}{2}$. Additionally, $L$ is a power of 2.

Is it possible to get a closed-form expression for the above infinite sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a closed-form expression for the above infinite sum?

Yes

Hint

1. Draw $x[n]$
2. Draw one time shift copy, e.g. $x[n-R]$, sum them
3. Draw a few more time shift copies, i.e.  $x[n-2R]$, $x[n+R]$
4. Sum them all up and see if you see the pattern.